# How to set div's width equal to another div using sass/css?

Tags: css, sass

I have first element:

```
 <div layout="column" layout-align="start center" class="focusBox flex "></div>
```

it's css:

```
.focusBox {
 margin-top: 2%;
 border: 1px solid $alto;
 height: calc(100vh - 182px);
 background-color: $white;
}
```

and second element:

```
<div flex class="subFolderBox" ></div>
```

it's css:

```
.subFolderBox {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  border: 1px solid $alto;
}
```

How to set width of first element to second using sass or css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

im not sure about css/scss but if you prefer with jquery you can do it like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".second_div").css({
    'width': ($(".first_div").width() + 'px')
  });
});
```

```css
.second_div,
.first_div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first_div">First Div some text</div>
<div class="second_div">Second.width </div>
```

Comment: without jquery?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `display: inline-grid` with a wrapper. No javascript needed. The columns are exactly equal.

```css
.second_div,
.first_div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first_div">A very very very very long text</div>
  <div class="second_div">A word</div>
</div>
```

Dynamic version:

```css
.second_div,
.first_div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first_div">A very very very very long text</div>
  <div class="second_div">A word</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first_div">A very very very very long text</div>
  <div class="second_div">A word</div>
  <div class="second_div">A word word word</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first_div">A very very very very long text</div>
  <div class="second_div">A word</div>
  <div class="second_div">A word</div>
  <div class="second_div">A word word word</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Easy and elegant, +1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this answer gave me the inspiration to keep the widths of 2 `divs` in sync that were placed one on top of the other.

Answer (score 3):

sass

```
$width:100px;

.focusBox {
  width: $width;
}

.subFolderBox {
  width: $width;
}
```

or css

```
.focusBox, .subFolderBox {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: you didnt get the question

Comment: you want to get the width of focusBox and set a same width on subFolderBox?

Comment: no. just one dive and it's some sibling include second divm which width I need to set like first one. I know I can make it using js get element width, but hope there is css way.

Comment: The above answer is the answer to the question: How to set two elements to be the same width, not an answer to the question: How to set the width of one element based on the width of the other element.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code i solve the issue.

```css
.paddingBlock {
 padding: 20px 0;
}
.equalHW{ background:red; margin-right:10px;}

.eqWrap {
 display: flex;
}

.equalHW {
 flex: 1;
}
.eq {
 padding: 10px;
}
.eq:nth-of-type(odd) {
 background: yellow;
}

.eq:nth-of-type(even) {
 background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="paddingBlock">
  <div class="equalHWrap eqWrap">
    <div class="equalHW eq">boo00000000000 <br> boo</div>
    <div class="equalHW eq">shoo</div>
    <div class="equalHW eq">clue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```